# Nouveau driver still in use after blacklist

Tags: 16.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

My setup: EVGA GTX 750Ti FTW Edition w/ ACX2.0

Lubuntu DE (Left unity because I game on this machine)

Using an HDTV (Phillips 32") w/ HDMI cable.

I've been trying for awhile now to fix my driver situation, I have already added

```
blacklist vga16fb
blacklist nouveau
blacklist rivafb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist rivatv
```

to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

(Now that I've added this to my blacklist, a proprietary driver appeared for xorg, wasn't there before so I guess it worked to some extent?)

I've already 'installed' the Nvidia drivers a few times aswell to no avail.

Using `lshw -c video` outputs:

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:fb000000-fbffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:de000000-dfffffff ioport:ef00(size=128) memory:fc000000-fc07ffff
```

`driver=nouveau`

The driver I'm trying to install is `NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-375.39`.

I've tried proprietary drivers such as: `Nvidia binary driver 367.57` `Nvidia binary driver 340.101` however, when using these I either get no video output at all or I'm stuck in a login loop.

(Same goes for most other Nvidia drivers aswell, they really hate me for some reason, either that or my 750Ti).

I've noticed that most of my games suffer from screen tearing and much worse performance FPS wise than Windows 10 (Made the full switch awhile back, all of the games I try to play are Linux ports from my steam library. So far only 2 work flawlessly).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

-Feg

Comment: Happened to me too... on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS it the driver coulb install, but yesterday on UbuntuMATE it didn't. same problem...

Answer (score 0):

My /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-nvidia-nouveau.conf:

```
blacklist nouveau
options nouveau modeset=0
blacklist nvidiafb
```

Then,

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Ctrl-Alt-F(1-5),

```
systemctl disable|stop lightdm
apt install xdm
```

Reboot.

Check nouveau not loaded:

```
lsmod

apt install nvidia-driver-435

systemctl enable xdm
```

Comment: I'm failing to see what lightdm has to do with nouveau